# Email not going through on live server but works through local host Xampp

Tags: php, html, xampp

Hey guys i am having this weird issue with sending information from my contact form to my email address. I have tested my code on local host through Xampp and i receive the emails perfectly fine, however when i uploaded the code to the server and submit. The success message shows as it should but no email is received, not even in the junk folder.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name1'];
$email = $_POST['email2'];
$message = $_POST['message3'];
$from = 'From: Testing';
$to = 'testing@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form Testing';

$body = "From: $name\n Email: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']){
    /*Do something when the submit has been pressed*/
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
        $_SESSION['Success'] = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your Message Has Been Sent!</div>';
        header('Location: index.php#fifthpage');
    } else{
        $_SESSION['Error'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Something Went Wrong Please Try Again!</div>';
        header('Location: index.php#fifthpage');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Then something wrong with ur SMTP setup on live server, check your php.ini - I'd suggest using PHPMailer class

Comment: hmm yeah i think that may be the case because when i changed the email that the messages are directed to with a gmail account the message now get sent. So i presume outlook may be blocking incoming requests?

Comment: No it should work, just use PHPMailer, than you can connect to your own SMTP server with your own credentials and send email that will very less likely go to spam - it is **extremely** easy and saves **alot** of headache

Answer (score -1):

```
    $to = 'testing@hotmail.com';
    $from = $_POST['email2'];
    $subject = 'Contact Form Testing';
    $body = $_POST['message3']."\r\n";
    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-to: $from";
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

if($sent){
echo "The message was sent";
}
else{
    echo "Sending failed";
}
```

Comment: That isn't my downvote, but they're already doing that `if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){...}` - Probably why you got that from someone (else).

Comment: No. I typed it by myself :)